# Determining a direction/projection/heading for an object in 3D space after it has been rotated

Tags: mathematics

I hope this is a good place to find an answer. I'm not a math wiz and I've tried to tackle this problem many times over the past decade or so.

I have a 3D space world, and I'm in a little space ship. I travel from point to point based on map waypoints. My game interface would allow me to rotate my (stationary for this example) ship in a gimbal fashion. What do i need to do to capture my new heading and project a new point to move to if I just rotated my ship and decide to travel forward? It would also be nice to capture something relative between the two rotations. There will be no real time movement in this example, although I understand lerp is a method to interpolate if I decided to up the complexity.

I've been through https://gamemath.com/ several times over the years, but what I think I am missing is a way to visualize or visually plot what's going on and see that the math functions work as intended, along with a way to practice.

Is Euler my solution, or matrices or quaternions best for my application? Like I mentioned, math has never been a strong point and I will never truly understand these concepts, so my best bet is to get help picking the best method and then implement it the best I can.

I've worked on this for long periods of time over the years, then end up dropping it as I cannot come up with a solution. The last time I tried I had dropped the entire project idea once and for all as it became hopeless to me to ever solve this step. Though even now a couple of years later, it still pulls at me and I cannot shake the desire to build my thing.

Thank you to anyone that may respond!

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific rotation operation you need help with. Try drawing a diagram of what you need?

Comment: The objects' world matrix (matrix that positions the object in the world) has the information you need. Depending on how you align your object the vector that is the forward direction is one of `vec3(m[0], m[1], m[2])` ,  `vec3(m[4], m[5], m[6])` , or most common `vec3(m[8], m[9], m[10])` with forward along the positive x, y, or z axis respectively, where `m` is `mat4`. If the model is scaled you will need to normalize the vector. Thus to move forward 10 units along the models  z axis   `modelPos += 10.0 * normalize(vec3(m[8], m[9], m[10]))`

Comment: @DMGregory I think I'm at a loss for information now. Based on what Blindman67 added, it seems I need to choose an environment to work in, the the tools will be available as a standard of operation, i.e: mat4 and vec3(). I'm kind of doing this on paper so to speak, so if my ship points a certain way and the ship where to "scan" it's immediate look-at area, I'd ask the database for objects and resources based on an area around the calculated projection.

Comment: If you want to be able to efficiently compose rotations, find the difference between two rotations, or interpolate rotations, quaternions are the way to go. Euler angles don't compose neatly and matrices can distort during interpolation. [All the rules you need to compute quaternion operations "on paper" are available on the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). Is there a specific use of them that you need help with?